# Many blogs served with one installation of Ghost blogging platform

Tags: ghost-blog

Is there any chance to run *single installation* of [Ghost blogging platform](https://ghost.org/download/) to serve *many blogs* accessible under many different top-level domains or subdomain?

I have tried to [browse source code](https://github.com/tryghost/Ghost), [Ghost's forum](https://ghost.org/forum) and read some [various articles](http://www.elegantthemes.com/blog/resources/wordpress-vs-ghost), but I still haven't managed to get one strike answers to this question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There seems to be an alternative way now:

> you could build multiple sites with something like Gatsby and source the content from a single Ghost install. Have you checked out our [*Gatsby Starter template to build lightning fast websites with Ghost & Gatsby* on GitHub](https://github.com/TryGhost/gatsby-starter-ghost)?

(Source: https://forum.ghost.org/t/ghost-multisite-setup-multiple-publications-from-one-ghost-instance/9139)

The idea is to use Ghost as a completely decoupled headless CMS and bring your own front-end written in Gatsby.js. See [demo](https://gatsby.ghost.org/about).

[image]

Answer (score 20):

Ah, I was to quick in asking, without doing proper research. No, it is not possible (currently) to run many blogs under many domains, served by one installation of Ghost.

To really serve many blogs, you need to have many installations of Ghost bind together with for example Nginx or any other solution for redirecting traffic from each domain to each specific installation of Ghost.

More information can be found here:

- Ghost's forum entry: [Ghost Installation as a Multisite like Wordpress Multisite wpmu](https://ghost.org/forum/installation/4421-ghost-installation-as-a-multisite-like-wordpress-multisite-wpmu/6/),
- Ghost's forum entry: [Multiple blogs - one running instance?](https://ghost.org/forum/installation/16261-multiple-blogs-one-running-instance/2/),
- DigitalOcean's article: [How To Serve Multiple Ghost Blogs on One VPS Using Nginx Server Blocks](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-serve-multiple-ghost-blogs-on-one-vps-using-nginx-server-blocks),
- The Node Dan's blog article: [A Ghost Workflow](http://seanvbaker.com/a-ghost-workflow/).

Ghost has introduced a feature of [having many users in one Ghost blog](https://ghost.org/forum/installation/4421-ghost-installation-as-a-multisite-like-wordpress-multisite-wpmu/6/), but as for base implementation of Ghost, there is absolutely no support for running multiple blogs / domain under one Ghost installation.